# Is it possible to change the clock frequency of Wifi chip?

Tags: linux, wifi

Is it possible under Linux to change the frequency of Wifi chips e.g. using Intel driver iwlwifi like we do for CPUs?

Comment: Do you mean the chip's clock frequency (which you might want to reduce to save power), and not the radio frequency (which determines what network you're connecting to)? At a hunch, I'd say no: the chip's clock has to run fast enough to process the signal.

Comment: Yes. I'm referring to chip's clock frequency. The idea is scale down the frequency depending on the wifi queue length or priorities of tasks, which cause wifi traffic. Something similar on the lines of CPU frequency scaling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A network adapter does not process tasks, queues, or priorities.  All it does is convert the message received on one interface to a format compatible with the other one.

There is also no way for the adapter to predict the processing that will be required in the next instant (let alone second).  Even if there was any logical justification to implement this, which there isn't, it would probably require more processing to manage it than what would be saved.

The only way to make such an adapter use less energy is to put it to sleep, if it supports it.  Of course it won't be able to handle any communication during sleep.